# Approximating RKHS norm with samples

Tags: gaussian-process, kernel-trick, functional-data-analysis

I have a function $f'$, sampled from a Gaussian process prior with a known kernel $f' \sim N(0,K)$.   Is it possible to find/approximate  a solution for $min_w||f_w-f'||^2_H$ if I can calculate both $f_w(x)$ and $f'(x)$ for some finite ${x_1,....x_n}$, were $f_w$ some flexible function (neural network for example) parametrized by $w$?

PS. and especially I've interested in connection between Hylbert norm in RKHS and it's quadratic form approximation $(f-f')^TK^{-1}(f-f')$ where the K is a Gram matrix generated by the same kernel as generated RKHS

Comment: How is the RKHS resp. its norm defined?

Comment: Like Theorem 2.4 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.02582.pdf